# User input working at backend but refuses to display at the front end (flask)

Tags: python, html, flask, chatbot, read.csv

I created a retrieval Chatbot which works fine with a json file.. The challenge I'm having is retrieving values from a csv file. For example a user wants to retrieve rows/columns with a particular heading. They are supposed to enter a numerical prompt (eg. 1) which searches the dB and returns results based on the item the user wants found. Everything works as planned out but on the cmd.. The results (prompts, outputs) refuse to display on the frontend (flask).

All I want is for the prompts to display on the frontend for user interaction. I've tried different things and no positive results yet .
[function to search csv file based on columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBkQ0.jpg)
[if, elif to differentiate between columns searches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52l06.jpg)
[code working fine in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpIbI.jpg)
[nothing from the frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhnrO.jpg)

#routes.py

```
def searchByProductDesc():
    product=input('Enter food item name\n')
    csv_file=csv.reader(open('chatbot_codes\GeneralProductPricing.csv','r'))

    for row in csv_file:
        if product==row[2]:
            c=str(print(row))
    return c

def searchByDate():
    product=input('Enter observed date of food prices\n')
    csv_file=csv.reader(open('chatbot_codes\GeneralProductPricing.csv','r'))

    for row in csv_file:
        if product==row[0]:
            c=str(print(row))
    return c

def searchByLocation():
    product=input('Enter the location of the market\n')
    csv_file=csv.reader(open('chatbot_codes\GeneralProductPricing.csv','r'))

    for row in csv_file:
        if product==row[4]:
            c=str(print(row))
    return c

def searchByMarketName():
    product=input('Enter the name of the market\n')
    csv_file=csv.reader(open('chatbot_codes\GeneralProductPricing.csv','r'))

    for row in csv_file:
        if product==row[5]:
            c=str(print(row))
    return c

def get_response(return_list,intents_json,text):

    if len(return_list)==0:
        tag='noanswer'
    else:
        tag=return_list[0]['intent']

    if tag=='prices':

        r = int(input('For food prices: \n Enter 1 to search by product name (eg. Bitterleaf) \n Enter 2 to search by observed date (eg. 03/03/2023) \n Enter 3 to search by market location (eg. Wuse, FCT Abuja) \n Enter 4 to search by market name (eg. Wuse Market) \n You may proceed... '))

        if r==1:
            x = searchByProductDesc()
            return x, 'prices'
        elif r==2:
            x = searchByDate()
            return x, 'prices'
        elif r==3:
            x = searchByLocation()
            return x, 'prices'
        elif r==4:
            x = searchByMarketName()
            return x, 'prices'
        else:
            x = 'Sorry, invalid input!'
            print(x)
            return x, 'prices'

@app.route("/get")
def chatbot():
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    resp=response(userText)
    return resp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I suggest taking a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And please don't [post pictures of your code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), instead copy paste the code into a code blocking using backticks (`) so others can more easily reproduce the error!

Comment: Thanks.. I'll reask it with this format you suggested.. I used my phone to ask so it was difficult copying codes from it..